# Compare date strings

Tags: python

I'm crawling past some articles posted in a certain date.
The following is part of my code:

```py
def get_articles(dom, date):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(dom, 'html.parser')

    articles = []
    divs = soup.find_all('div', "r-ent")
    for d in divs:
        print("A")
        print(d.find('div', 'date').string, date)
        if d.find('div', 'date').string == date: #Where the problem is.
            print("YYYYYYYYYY")
            ...
    return articles


    import time
    page = get_web_page('https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/joke/index.html')

    if page:
        date = time.strftime("%m/%d").lstrip('0') # date is string
        current_articles = get_articles(page, date)
        for post in current_articles:
            print(post)
```

```
    #A 
    #2/01 2/01
    #A 
    #2/01 2/01
    #A 
    #2/01 2/01
    #A 
    #2/01 2/01
    #A 
    #2/01 2/01
    #A 
    #2/01 2/01
    #A 
    #2/01 2/01
    #A 
    #11/04 2/01
```

Ideally, the `YYYYYYYYYY` should be printed when
`d.find('div', 'date').string == date`

Why does the code execute not ideally and how do I edit it?

Comment: Try `print(repr(d.find('div', 'date').string), repr(date))`

Comment: I tried. The result is ' 2/01' '2/01' and the different is one has a blank(from origin website) and the other doesn't(from time).
Is it possible to remove the blank?

Comment: I completed! 
`repr(d.find('div', 'date').string.lstrip()) == repr(date)` can work!

Comment: @niummxvy Mind adding your solution as an answer for others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comment, I use repr() to check where the difference is.

```
repr(d.find('div', 'date').string.lstrip()) == repr(date)
# ' 2/01' '2/01'
```

So I need to remove the blank

```
d.find('div', 'date').string.lstrip() == date
# '2/01' '2/01'
```

Then the condition is true.